# C++ typechecks performed when assigning one pointer to another

Tags: c++, typechecking

I am wondering the extend of type checks the compiler does in the following

```
class Parent{
};

class Child : public Parent{
};

class Unrelated{
};

main(){
  Parent* p = new Child() // OK. But type of p is still Parent* and not Child*
  Unrelatead* u = new Child() // Not OK. Child* is not Unrelated*.
}
```

So, in the first assignment, the p now points to the 'Parent' object within Child, whereas the second assignment is not allowed at all, although ultimately both p and u will hold memory addresses.

What exactly checks does the compiler perform during these assignments and at what part of compilation does the compiler enforce these checks?

Comment: What do you mean by "where are those checks"?

Comment: And what do you mean by "What exactly checks does the compiler perform"? It is a simple static type checking, no?

Comment: I meant the underlying data is going to be memory address (unsigned long), so how does the compiler understand that I need to not only look at the fact that this is unsigned long, but also that this is a pointer and what the type of the object it is pointing to is

Comment: The compiler performs the same exact checks you have performed when you decided that the first assignment is OK and the second one is not.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler allows assigning data pointers:

1. When both are pointers to the same type, or the destination pointer is a pointer to a more restrictively `const`/`volatile` qualified type, e.g. `T*` to `T const volatile*`.
2. A pointer to a derived class can be assigned to a pointer to an accessible base class with a similar or more restrictive `const`/`volatile` qualification, e.g. `Derived*` to `Base const*`.
3. Any data pointer to `void*` with a similar or more restrictive `const`/`volatile` qualification, e.g. `T const*` to `void const*`.

`Parent* p = new Child();` compiles because it is case 2.

`Unrelatead* u = new Child();` doesn't compile because it is none of the above cases. To make the assignment between unrelated data pointers work a `reinterpret_cast<>` is required.

Answer (score 0):

The first assignment is okay, because compilers will arrange all the memory of the base class in front of the memory of the derived class.
You can thus upcast pointers, since all the fields of the base class will still be pointed to.

The second assignment is not okay, because `Child` does not inherit from `Unrelated` and so their memory layout may be different.
The compiler keeps track of these class hierarchies.
These checks only happen at compile-time.

Note that upcasting pointers can be dangerous.
If your class is not virtual, `delete p` will not call the destructor of the derived class, leading to potential memory leaks.
If you decide to upcast and `delete` pointers, make sure you are doing it for virtual classes.